# Task.Factory.StartNew is not working in console c# application

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I am having a console application which reads the messages from Console.OpenStandardInput();
I am doing this in a task. but it seems to be not working.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
        {
    wtoken = new CancellationTokenSource();
            readInputStream = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                wtoken.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                while (true)
                { 
                    if (wtoken.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        wtoken.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       OpenStandardStreamIn();
                    }
                }
            }, wtoken.Token
            );
     Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Here is my OpenStandardStreamIn function

```
   public static void OpenStandardStreamIn()
        {
                Stream stdin = Console.OpenStandardInput();
                int length = 0;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
                stdin.Read(bytes, 0, 4);
                length = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
                string input = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    input += (char)stdin.ReadByte();
                }
                Console.Write(input);
            }
```

Any help? why it is not working in a continous loop

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What happens exactly?

Comment: Which loop are you talking about? You have not started new task in side any loop, if that is what you wanted to do. Also you are not waiting for the Task started to complete before ReadLine ..

Comment: @galenus : it is just going through it once while compiling and then starts waiting for input for Console.ReadLine(); when i add the input it is completing and the dubugging stopped

Comment: @bit: Ya you are right, but inside the task there is a infinite while loop. will it not work? I thought the task will start as soon as i define Task.Factory.StartNew. m i wrong on this?

Comment: @bit :  if i do readInputStream.Start(). it will show exception that "Start may not be called on a task that was already started."

Comment: I think it will start when you do a Task.Wait()

Comment: @bit: may be the case. i will try and let you know bit to add it as an answer if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically have a race condition between `Console.ReadLine` and your task. Both of them are trying to read from standard input - and I certainly don't know what you should expect when reading from standard input from two threads at the same time, but it seems like something worth avoiding.

You can easily test this by changing the task to do something *other* than reading from standard input. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var wtoken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var readInputStream = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
        }, wtoken.Token);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

If your real code needs to read from standard input, then I suggest you change `Console.ReadLine()` into `readInputStream.Wait()`. I'd also suggest you use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew()` if you're using .NET 4.5, just for readability - assuming you don't need any of the more esoteric behaviour of `TaskFactory.StartNew`.

Comment: Thanks For the answer Jon. Console.Readline was just a cheap trick to avoid the application to get stopped. and i need to read the standard input stream to get the messages from chrome extension. basically it is a native messaging application.

Comment: Should I create a seperate thread for task and use Wait function? how can i hold the console application to execute continously?

Comment: @Shiv: Why do you need a separate thread at all? If you just need to read from standard input, just read from standard input...

Comment: because the console application is also connect to the winform via named pipe. The communication b/w them should not blocked by this task. and i only need to read  from standard input when i got command from winform. how can i make my console app keep running in that case?"

Comment: @Shiv: It sounds like you really need to ask a new question with a lot more context. I've explained why the code you've provided hasn't worked - but there's no point in dragging out bits of extra information one comment at a time, leading to something which is entirely different from your original question.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I will mark your answer and ask a new question for that.